# Check data present in list of object array

Tags: java

I have a list of object :

```
List<Object[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
Object[] object = {"test", "test1", "test2"};
list.add(object);
```

List contains some data.

I have another string `String str = "test";`

I am using below code. What are best other ways:

```
for (Object []object1 : list) {
     for (Object obj : object1) {
        if (obj.equals("test")) {
          System.out.println("true");
        }
     }
}
```

How to check this string present in above list with minimum of code.

Comment: Simple use contains () method

Answer (score 2):

Java 8 introduced [Streams](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html) which are powerful, yet code-compact as you demanded. This answer uses more features of Java 8 sucha as [Lambdas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) and [Method References](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).

Here is a one-liner instruction:

```
boolean containsObject = list.stream().flatMap(Arrays::stream).filter(s->str.equals(s) ).findFirst().isPresent();
```

Here how it works:

```
boolean containsObject = list.stream() // Turning the List into a Stream of Arrays
    .flatMap(Arrays::stream)           // flattening the 2D structure into a single-dimensional stream of Objects (Note: using a Method reference)
    .filter(s->str.equals(s))          // Filtering the flat stream to check for equality (Note: using a Lambda expression)
    .findFirst()                       // Demands to find the first  Occurence that passed the Filter test
    .isPresent();                      // Collapse the stream and returns the result of the above demand (Note: the Stream makes no computation until this instruction)
```

This solution is code-compact, and brings the nice features of Streams such as parallelization and laziness.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you convert the `Object[]`s to lists, then you can call their `contains(Object)`. You could either have `list` be a `List<List<Object>>`, or you could leave it with `Object[]` and wrap the `Object[]`s in a `List` as-needed.

Example of the "convert as needed":

```
for(Object[] object1 : list)
    if(Arrays.asList(object1).contains("test"))
        System.out.println("true");
```

Personally, I would have `list` be a `List<List>`. Whenever you add to it, just wrap your arrays in a list. Assuming `arr` is an `Object[]`, that means `list.add(Arrays.asList(arr));`.

Alexander's answer is also correct (I think; I didn't examine it too closely), but I find long strings of stream operators to be less readable. If you disagree with my opinion on that, then use the stream operators.